# php regexp for any kind of character

Tags: regex

I use this pattern:

```
'/({for) (\d+) (times})([\w+\d+{}]{0,})({endfor})/i'
```

to convert

```
{for 3 times}App2{endfor}
```

in

```
App2  App2  App2
```

But this do not work with:

```
{for 7 times}
    App2
{endfor}
```

---

**This is a little piece of my very little template engine.**

*It's just for fun*

```
$mactos = Array(
    '/({for) (\d+) (times})([\w+\d+{}]{0,})({endfor})/i' => '<?php for($i=0;$i<${2};$i++) : ?> ${4} <?php endfor; ?' . '>',
    '/({{)(\w+)(}})/i' => '<?php echo $${2}; ?' . '>'
);
$php = file_get_contents('teamplate.php');
foreach ($this->getPatternAndReplacement() as $pattern => $replacement) {
    $php = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $php);
}
```

---

I've read that (...) catch anything but with

```
'/({for) (\d+) (times})(...)({endfor})/i'
```

does not work =(.

Comment: Side note: Most metacharacters lose special meaning inside character classes, so you're allowing literal `+` chars. Assuming you don't mean to accept literal `+` chars, `[\w+\d+{}]{0,}` appears to be equivalent to `[\w{}]*` (since `*` means `{0,}` and `\d` is included within `\w`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you literally mean `(...)`, that is a group that matches exactly three characters. `(.+)` would match one or more of any characters, except...

---

By default, `.` matches anything *except* newlines.

> **s (PCRE_DOTALL)**
> If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded.

Use the [`s` modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) to allow `.` to match newline characters.

```
/your pattern/s
```

---

*Example (also [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/aHyru2))*:

```php
$str = <<<STR
{for 7 times}
    App2
{endfor}
STR;

preg_match('/({for) (\d+) (times})(.+)({endfor})/s', $str, $matchParts);

print_r($matchParts);
```

```
OUTPUT:

Array
(
    [0] => {for 7 times}
    App2
{endfor}
    [1] => {for
    [2] => 7
    [3] => times}
    [4] => 
    App2

    [5] => {endfor}
)
```

Comment: It's ok, but I'll like to understand why does not work with two for like:$str = <<<STR
{for 7 times}
    App2
{endfor}
{for 7 times}
    App2
{endfor}
STR;

Comment: Ok: I dont need to create yet another template engine. This work it's just for fun. Thank you Wiseguy.

Comment: @SimoneDemoGentili Thanks. To answer your question, `preg_match()` only matches once; you want `preg_match_all()` for multiple matches. Also, you would make your wildcard `(.+)` lazy (ungreedy) like this `(.+?)` so it will not match too far. See [example here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/cfWo19).

Comment: @SimoneDemoGentili Experimenting for fun is great learning! :-) By the way, something like a template engine might be too complex for a single regex, so you'd probably be better off writing your own parser/tokenizer for it.

Comment: you use preg_match* functions instead of preg_replace. Why? You suggest me to pass through preg_match*?

Comment: @SimoneDemoGentili Oh, no, I thought you meant why my example didn't match multiple. Do note the lazy quantifier. That's probably key.

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Modifiers".