# URL Rewrite Matching Regex to a "?" in the URL

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, web-config

I am using iis 7 and trying to create a rewrite rule that will look for the following URL:

```
http://www.example.com/Toys/?GOOGLE/USA/Wood/trains
```

I'm using the following web.config which works if I omit the "?" from the URL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Toys" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^Toys/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/toys/index.cfm?a={R:1}&amp;b={R:2}&amp;c={R:3}&amp;d={R:4}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

They already have the "?" hard coded in a few thousand URLS submitted to the search engines for PPC urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

```
Toys/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/dGjT1qqYSQydzcve)

Eliminating the [start-of-line anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22759143/578411) (the `^`) matches your example url. With the anchor, it doesn't match, because there's text before the `Toys`.

Note, however, the url I put on the second line, which contains extra path elements. Your regex captures `?GOOGLE/USA/Wood/trains` in the *first group*, because each element in your regex is `.+` which is "[*any* character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13594017), and as many as possible". Because it's [greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764399), it consumes these extra elements.

It would be safer to exclude slashes from each captured portion:

```
Toys/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/igIsvP9VqwYabwpy)

Note the difference in what it captures: Never more than four path elements, and only one element in each capture group.

An alternative (which is fine, but I prefer the slash-version above) is to make each element in your original regex [reluctant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764399):

```
Toys/(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/jt7dZYL23zbPsAI5)

- **Greedy** causes that portion of the regex to match *as much as possible* (as long as the overall regex can still match).
- **Reluctant** causes that portion to match *as little as possible* (as long as the overall regex can still match).

---

Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference.

Comment: Thank you.  Your Regex was right on the money.  I used the /'s technique in the first at the stop, but I think that when coldfusion see's the ? its grabbing the whole thing.  I used iis7's pattern tester in the iis manager and it shows me what I want to see but coldfusion is doing something different