# Adding line breaks and tabs to (.*)

Tags: python, regex

For extracting everything between two different regular expression structures, I use this:

`%%Different Regular Expressions%%(.*)%%Different Regular Expressions%%`

The problem with using `(.*)` is that it doesn't contain line breaks (`\n*`). Is there any way to modify this structure or using a more efficient structure instead of this for extracting everything between two defined regular expressions?

Comment: To me new, that `.` would not mach tabs : ) I think only no newlines. You might also want to mention the environment where you're using the regex.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php regexp for any kind of character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593948/php-regexp-for-any-kind-of-character)

Comment: @bobblebubble Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use s flag, it makes dot(.) matches newline

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Gz2ly/2)

Note: As @bobblebubble mentioned in comments in python you can use re.DOTALL for s flag

Comment: @Eghbal I think in Python you can use `re.DOTALL` or the [inline flag `(?s)`](https://regex101.com/r/FQf8WP/1)